# Entity Framework (Code First Dynamically Building a Model) - autoincrement don't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, auto-increment

I have a classes my domain(in assembly "Domains.dll"). I dynamically add to my DbContext Dbset load classes of assembly.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
public MyContext() : base("DBConnection"){}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Domains.dll");
   var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
   var list = assembly.GetTypes().OrderBy(i => i.GetType().Name);
   foreach (Type item in list)
   {
       entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item)
 .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
   }

   }
 }

public abstract class Entity
{
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int Id { get; set; }
}
[Table("Person")]
public class Person : Entity
{
 public string FirstName {get ;set;}
 public string LastName {get ;set;}
}
```

After creating a new database I add new Person. An error that can not insert a null in the field Id. Autoincrement does not work. If I will not add a dynamic entity will create an empty database then the code will work.

```
public class PersonContext: DbContext
{
 public PersonContext() : base("DBConnection"){}

 public IDbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

using (PersonContext context = new PersonContext())
    {
        Person user = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "first",
            LastName = "last"
        };
        context.Persons.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What could be the problem? How much is auto-increment does not work?

Comment: The code worked just fine for me, What is the exact error text? I executed exactly what you put in the question without any problem

Comment: I dynamically add to my DbContext Dbset load classes of assembly. I added the code load in question. If context static - it works, if dynamic - not works.

Comment: Can you add the function you use to add Person please.

Comment: I add the code that is the question:    Person user = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "first",
            LastName = "last"
        };

Comment: I mean the type to the dbContext, the generic function you get using Reflection in the line typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity"); I think the function holds the key to the problem

Comment: check this: https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/